# How of I compute the following Rieman-Stieltijes integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

$\int_{[0,1]^2} |x+y|\ d\alpha(x,y)$, where $\alpha(x,y)=max(x,y)$?

Do I split the integral in two region as in the classical Riemann integral?